# Rails CSV Import Duplicates Created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I'm loading a lot of data into my application. I have over 40 models with data that I'm loading into it. All but one of these tables are importing fine. In the one table I'm having problems with every row is duplicated, so rather than having 234,225 rows I end up with 468,450 rows. Definitely not what I'm looking for. Each row is perfectly duplicated.

As part of this import I'm also flattening out the data structure. So I'm populating lookup fields into the main sku table.

Here is my code I'm using to import this skus table.

namespace :upload_data do

```
  desc "Load Skus"
  task :load_skus => :environment do
    require 'csv'
    require 'net/ftp'
    start_time = Time.now
    ftp = Net::FTP.new('<ftp location>')
    ftp.login(user = "<username>", passwd = "<password>")
    ftp.passive = true
    ftp.get("sku.csv", File.basename( "/data/sku.csv"))
    ftp.quit()
    upload = File.join('sku.csv')
      logcount=0
      CSV.foreach(upload, :headers => false) do |row|
        # roa = Roa.find_by_roa_code(row[21])
        # if roa
        #   roa_name = roa.roa_name
        # else
        #   roa_name = nil
        # end  

        #ROA      
        roa = Roa.find_by_roa_code(row[21])
        roa_name = roa && roa.roa_name

        #THER   
        ther = Ther.find_by_thera_class_code_int(row[50] && row[50].to_i)
        thera_class_desc = ther && ther.thera_class_desc

        #DEA
        dea = Dea.find_by_dea_class_code(row[45])
        dea_class_desc = dea && dea.dea_class_desc

        #LBLY2K
        lbly2k = Lbly2k.find_by_mfg_code(row[56])
        labeler_code = lbly2k && lbly2k.labeler_code
        rebate_status = lbly2k && lbly2k.rebate_status
        rebate_effective_date  = lbly2k && lbly2k.rebate_effective_date   
        rebate_termination_date = lbly2k && lbly2k.rebate_termination_date   

        #FORM      
        form = Form.find_by_master_form_code(row[22])
        form_desc = form && form.form_desc

        #PRODCAT      
        prodcat = Prodcat.find_by_product_category(row[26] && row[26].to_i.to_s)
        product_cat_desc = prodcat && prodcat.product_cat_desc

        #EXPGENRC      
        expgenrc = Expgenrc.find_by_gcr_code(row[52])
        gcr_exp_name = expgenrc && expgenrc.gcr_exp_name

        #GCR      
        gcr = Gcr.find_by_gcr_code(row[52])
        gcr_name = gcr && gcr.gcr_name

        #MFORM      
        mform = Mform.find_by_master_form_code(row[22])
        master_form_desc = mform && mform.master_form_desc

        #Orange Book Data
        orange = Orange.find_by_orange_book_code(row[31])
        orange_book_desc = orange && orange.orange_book_desc

        #EXDRUG      
        exdrug = Exdrug.find_by_exceptional_drug(row[44])
        exceptional_drug_desc = exdrug && exdrug.exceptional_drug_desc

        #MEASURE      
        measure = Measure.find_by_measure_code(row[39])
        measure_desc = measure && measure.measure_desc

        #JCODE      
        jcode = Jcode.find_by_ndc(row[13] && row[13].gsub('-', ''))
        puts "found jcode: #{jcode.inspect}"
        j_code = jcode && jcode.j_code
        j_code_desc = jcode && jcode.j_code_desc

        #GFC
        gfc = Gfc.find_by_gcr_code(row[52])
        gfc_master_code = gfc && gfc.gfc_master_code
        gfc_deact = gfc && gfc.gfc_deact 

        #packstren      
        packstren = Packstren.find_by_ndc(row[13] && row[13].gsub('-', ''))
        puts "Found Packstren #{packstren.inspect}"
        package_ID = packstren && packstren.package_ID
        puts "Package_ID is #{package_ID}"
        strength_code = packstren && packstren.strength_code 

        #STRENGTH 
        strength = Strength.find_by_strength_code(strength_code)
        puts "Found strength: #{strength.inspect}"
        strength_name_long = strength && strength.strength_name_long
        puts "Strength name long is #{strength_name_long}"

        #EXPSTREN 
        expstren = Expstren.find_by_strength_code(strength_code)
        strength_exp_name = expstren && expstren.strength_exp_name
        puts "Strength_exp_name is #{strength_exp_name}"

        #AWP
        awp = Awp.find_by_ndc(row[13] && row[13].gsub('-', ''))
        puts "Found awp: #{awp.inspect}"
        effective_date = awp && awp.effective_date
        puts "found effective_date: #{effective_date}"
        manufacturer_cmsid = awp && awp.manufacturer_cmsid
        puts "found manufacturer_cmsid: #{manufacturer_cmsid}"
        package_cmsid = awp && awp.package_cmsid 
        puts "found package_cmsid: #{package_cmsid}"

        Sku.create(:record_change           => row[0], 
                   :record_change_date      => row[1], 
                   :price_change_date       => row[2], 
                   :add_flag                => row[3], 
                   :add_date                => row[4], 
                   :deactivate_flag         => row[5], 
                   :deactivate_date         => row[6], 
                   :reactivate_flag         => row[7], 
                   :reactivate_date         => row[8], 
                   :filler1                 => row[9], 
                   :prev_ndc_awp_eff_date   => row[10], 
                   :prev_ndc_awp_pack_price => row[11], 
                   :prev_ndc_disc_date      => row[12], 
                   :ndc                     => row[13].gsub('-',''),
                   :j_code                  => j_code,
                   :j_code_desc             => j_code_desc,
                   :package_ID              => package_ID,
                   :strength_code           => strength_code,
                   :filler2                 => row[14], 
                   :ndc_orig_config         => row[15].gsub('-',''), 
                   :ndc10                   => row[16].gsub('-',''), 
                   :ndc_change_flag         => row[17], 
                   :prev_ndc                => row[18], 
                   :prev_ndc_config         => row[19], 
                   :prev_ndc10              => row[20], 
                   :roa_code                => row[21], 
                   :roa_name                => roa_name,
                   # :roa_name              => Roa.find_by_roa_code(row[21]) && Roa.find_by_roa_code(row[21]).roa_name,
                   :master_form_code        => row[22], 
                   :master_form_desc        => master_form_desc,
                   :form_desc               => form_desc,
                   :product_name            => row[23], 
                   :additional_desc         => row[24], 
                   :mfg_name_long           => row[25], 
                   :product_category        => row[26], 
                   :product_cat_desc        => product_cat_desc,
                   :solid_liquid            => row[27], 
                   :form_code               => row[28], 
                   :metric_size             => row[29], 
                   :strength_name           => row[30], 
                   :orange_book_code        => row[31],
                   :orange_book_desc        => orange_book_desc, 
                   :filler3                 => row[32], 
                   :orange_book_std_flag    => row[33], 
                   :unit_dose_flag          => row[34], 
                   :dispensing_unit_flag    => row[35], 
                   :package_size            => row[36], 
                   :package_qty_code        => row[37], 
                   :product_size            => row[38], 
                   :measure_code            => row[39],
                   :measure_desc            => measure_desc, 
                   :filler4                 => row[40], 
                   :top_volume_rank         => row[41], 
                   :single_source_flag      => row[42], 
                   :maintenance_drug_flag   => row[43], 
                   :exceptional_drug        => row[44],
                   :exceptional_drug_desc   => exceptional_drug_desc, 
                   :dea_class_code          => row[45],
                   :dea_class_desc          => dea_class_desc, 
                   :filler5                 => row[46], 
                   :filler6                 => row[47], 
                   :desi_drug_flag          => row[48], 
                   :desi_effective_date     => row[49], 
                   :thera_class_code        => row[50],
                   :thera_class_desc        => thera_class_desc, 
                   :generic_class_code      => row[51], 
                   :gcr_code                => row[52],
                   :gcr_exp_name            => gcr_exp_name,
                   :gcr_name                => gcr_name,
                   :gfc_master_code         => gfc_master_code,
                   :gfc_deact               => gfc_deact,
                   :gfc_code                => row[53], 
                   :stc_package_size        => row[54], 
                   :unit_of_measure         => row[55], 
                   :mfg_code                => row[56], 
                   :labeler_code            => labeler_code,
                   :rebate_status           => rebate_status,
                   :rebate_effective_date   => rebate_effective_date,
                   :rebate_termination_date => rebate_termination_date,
                   :wac_start_flag          => row[57], 
                   :wac_p_price             => row[58], 
                   :wac_u_price             => row[59], 
                   :wac_eff_date            => row[60], 
                   :wac1pre_p_price         => row[61], 
                   :wac1pre_u_price         => row[62], 
                   :wac1pre_eff_date        => row[63], 
                   :wac2pre_p_price         => row[64], 
                   :wac2pre_u_price         => row[65], 
                   :wac2pre_eff_date        => row[66], 
                   :filler7                 => row[67], 
                   :filler8                 => row[68], 
                   :filler9                 => row[69], 
                   :awp_start_flag          => row[70], 
                   :awp_p_price             => row[71], 
                   :awp_u_price             => row[72], 
                   :awp_eff_date            => row[73], 
                   :awp1pre_p_price         => row[74], 
                   :awp1pre_u_price         => row[75], 
                   :awp1pre_eff_date        => row[76], 
                   :awp2pre_p_price         => row[77], 
                   :awp2pre_u_price         => row[78], 
                   :awp2pre_eff_date        => row[79], 
                   :dp_start_flag           => row[80], 
                   :dp_p_price              => row[81], 
                   :dp_u_price              => row[82], 
                   :dp_eff_date             => row[83], 
                   :dp1pre_p_price          => row[84], 
                   :dp1pre_u_price          => row[85], 
                   :dp1pre_eff_date         => row[86], 
                   :dp2pre_p_price          => row[87], 
                   :dp2pre_u_price          => row[88], 
                   :dp2pre_eff_date         => row[89], 
                   :ful_start_flag          => row[90], 
                   :ful_p_price             => row[91], 
                   :ful_u_price             => row[92], 
                   :ful_eff_date            => row[93], 
                   :ful_pre_p_price         => row[94], 
                   :ful_pre_u_price         => row[95], 
                   :ful_pre_eff_date        => row[96], 
                   :ful2_pre_p_price        => row[97], 
                   :ful2_pre_u_price        => row[98], 
                   :ful2_pre_eff_date       => row[99], 
                   :srp_start_flag          => row[100], 
                   :srp_p_price             => row[102], 
                   :srp_u_price             => row[102], 
                   :srp_eff_date            => row[103], 
                   :srp1pre_p_price         => row[104], 
                   :srp1pre_u_price         => row[105], 
                   :srp1pre_eff_date        => row[106], 
                   :srp2pre_p_price         => row[107], 
                   :srp2pre_u_price         => row[108], 
                   :srp2pre_eff_date        => row[109])

      logcount += 1
    end
    total_time = Time.now - start_time
      puts "Successfully added #{logcount} Skus. Elapsed time #{total_time} seconds."

  end

end
```

Any ideas what I'm doing which is causing each row to be imported?

Thanks

Comment: Is ```log_count``` 234,225 or 468,450 after the import?

Comment: Original csv file has 234,225 rows. The log_count after the import is 468,450. Resulting table also has 468,450 rows.

Comment: Until you get your head around it, try looking in the DB first to see if that row exists somehow before you create it. Try #first_or_create method.

Comment: This is what I would do.  Clear your DB.  Before you create or save the order, try looking for the same order in the DB.  If it's not found, create new order.  This is just a simple fix, but it'll work.  The cause might be you're going through the loop twice like opening the CSV file twice in different part of your code perhaps?  I would look at your log file and see what it's doing